# Merging data with two columns in object format

Tags: python, pandas

I have two datasets and I want to merge these two tables with the left join function. Below you can see the structure of data:

```
Table 1

Index(['', '01', '02', '03', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '11', '12', '13',
       '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26',
       '27', '28', '29', '31', '32', '33', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '41',
       '42', '43', '45', '46', '47', '49', '51', '52', '53', '55', '56', '58',
       '59', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '68', '69', '71', '72', '73',
       '74', '75', '77', '78', '79', '81', '82', '84', '85', '86', '87', '88',
       '91', '92', '93', '94', '95', '96', '98', '99', 'K'],
      dtype='object')

Table 2

    Index(['0', '01', '02', '03', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12',
           '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24',
           '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '35', '36', '37',
           '38', '39', '41', '42', '43', '45', '46', '47', '49', '50', '51', '52',
           '53', '55', '56', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66',
           '68', '69', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '77', '78', '79', '80',
           '81', '82', '84', '85', '86', '87', '88', '90', '91', '92', '93', '94',
           '95', '96', '97', '98', '99', 'K'],
          dtype='object')
```

In these tables, I apply this function

```
data=pd.merge(table1,table2,on='key', how='left',indicator=True)
```

But although numbers stored as text are there Python can't match it e.g 45,46,92,94 etc.

Any suggestion on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried this https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html ?

Comment: @ Capie  This is about the type of data.  I have a problem with joining or matching functions because all of these data are not matched

Comment: @silent_hunter I think   table1.join(table2)    will result what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, this solution may be what you are looking for.

```
import pandas as pd

tb1 = ['', '01', '02', '03', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '11', '12', '13',
       '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26',
       '27', '28', '29', '31', '32', '33', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '41',
       '42', '43', '45', '46', '47', '49', '51', '52', '53', '55', '56', '58',
       '59', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '68', '69', '71', '72', '73',
       '74', '75', '77', '78', '79', '81', '82', '84', '85', '86', '87', '88',
       '91', '92', '93', '94', '95', '96', '98', '99', 'K']

tb2 = ['0', '01', '02', '03', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12',
           '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24',
           '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '35', '36', '37',
           '38', '39', '41', '42', '43', '45', '46', '47', '49', '50', '51', '52',
           '53', '55', '56', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66',
           '68', '69', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '77', '78', '79', '80',
           '81', '82', '84', '85', '86', '87', '88', '90', '91', '92', '93', '94',
           '95', '96', '97', '98', '99', 'K']

tb1 = pd.DataFrame (tb1, columns = ['column_name'])
tb1 = tb1.set_index('column_name')
tb2 = pd.DataFrame (tb2, columns = ['column_name'])
tb2 = tb2.set_index('column_name')
data = [tb1,tb2]
data = pd.concat(data) #to put the data in the same column
data2 = tb1.join(tb2) #to put the data in the same row but in different columns
```